# How to decode MongoDB bindata type to UUID string in SQL Server

Tags: mongodb, etl, bindata

I am migrating data from MongoDB to SQL server using an ETL tool (SSIS).

There are bindata type 0 fields that are brought across as $binary and $type pairs. I want to know how I can decode this on SQL server side to represent it as a UUID string.

For example.

In MongoDB:

```
BinData(0, '+d5gI8MYTUCgoSXnkERZLA==')
```

Desired output in SQL Server:

```
f9de6023-c318-4d40-a0a1-25e79044592c
```